# Is it possible to encrypt any file with a password/hash using powershell or even cmd?

Tags: powershell, encryption

And if its possible, whats the easiest and shortest way to do so? 
E.g I want to encrypt a text file that contains personal information and I want to encrypt it with a Password so that nobody can ready it without decrypting it using the correct password.

Comment: With PowerShell see `Get-Help Get-FileHash` in cmd see `certutil /?` or search these keywords with google

Answer (score 4):

Encrypt/Decrypt files using symmetrical encryption

This PowerShell module includes 3 cmdlets to create an cryptography key, encypt a file, and decrypt a file. This was developed with the idea of testing defenses against ransomware in mind, but can also be used for securely storing and accessing information within a script.

```
#Create Key 
$key = New-CryptographyKey -Algorithm AES 

#Encrypt the file 
Protect-File '.\secrets.txt' -Algorithm AES -Key $key -RemoveSource 

#Decrypt the file 
Unprotect-File '.\secrets.txt.AES' -Algorithm AES -Key $key -RemoveSource
```

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/EncryptDecrypt-files-use-65e7ae5d

https://blog.ipswitch.com/automating-security-controls-using-powershell-to-automate-data-encryption